# How to render report as HTML in in .NET reporting

Tags: html, reporting-services, rdlc

We are using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport   (RDLC)

Only 4 render extensions, pdf, excel, image and 1 more are available.

We want to render the report as HTML finally. How can we do that ? Any related suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a `ReportViewer` control to your page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(v=VS.100).aspx